# Parsing OpenXML document [Windows Store Apps/Metro Apps]

Tags: microsoft-metro, openxml, openxml-sdk, windows-store-apps

I do not feel like reinventing the whole wheel on Windows Store Apps, but is there any readily available way that I am able to parse OpenXML document quickly on Windows Store Apps?

I had been using the OpenXML SDK (currently on 2.5) but it is unfortunately tied with `WindowsBase` and I can't reference it in my project.

I read somewhere which mentioned that I should be looking at `Windows.IO.Packaging`, I do understand that OpenXML is a container of all files, but that is "reinventing the whole wheel" to me already, and I need to go down to the file access level to read the `WorkBookPart` and WorkSheetPart` (... blah blah blah).

Thanks!~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I took the chance to learn OpenXML and was able to parse the .XLSX file on my own. It wasn't as difficult as I initially feared. The fact that we can use `ZipArchive` to help derive the corresponding Sheet, coupling with the use of `Linq to Xml` means that a custom-made `ExcelReader` class takes about 1 hour to write.

Comment: Would you be willing to share the code for creating a PowerPoint with charts from a windows store app. I would be really interested in looking at that?